# Download NFe / NFEPHP

Tags: php, nfe

Bom dia, estou consultando as NFe de determinado cliente, até aí tudo bem, está retornando as Chave das notas tudo certinho, mas quando utilizo a opção de download, o mesmo retorna 'Servico Paralisado sem Previsao', em uma leitura rápida, observei que este serviço de Download 'NfeDownloadNF', foi descontinuado, gostaria de saber como efetuar o download da NFe utilizando o 'NfeDistribuicaoDFe', segue trecho de código...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
require_once '../../bootstrap.php';
use NFePHP\NFe\ToolsNFe;
$nfe = new ToolsNFe('../../config/config.json');
$nfe->setModelo('55');
$ultNSU = 0;
$numNSU = 0;
$tpAmb = '1';
$cnpj = '';
$aResposta = array();
$aRespostaDownload = array();
$xml = $nfe->sefazDistDFe('AN', $tpAmb, $cnpj, $ultNSU, $numNSU, $aResposta);
foreach ($aResposta['aDoc'] as $k => $v) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($v['doc']);
    $xml = get_object_vars($xml);
    if (isset($xml['vNF'])) {
        $dados = array(
            'chnfe' => $xml['chNFe'],
            'cnpj' => $xml['CNPJ'],
            'xnome' => utf8_decode($xml['xNome']),
            'ie' => $xml['IE'],
            'data' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($xml['dhEmi'])),
            'tpnf' => $xml['tpNF'],
            'vnf' => $xml['vNF'],
            'nprot' => $xml['nProt'],
            'csitnfe' => $xml['cSitNFe'],
            'nsu' => $v['NSU']
        );
        $resp = $nfe->sefazDownload($dados['chnfe'], $tpAmb, $cnpj, $aRespostaDownload);
        var_dump($aRespostaDownload);exit();
    }
}
echo '<br><br><PRE>';
echo htmlspecialchars($nfe->soapDebug);
echo '</PRE><BR>';
print_r($aResposta);
echo "<br>";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia Felipe, apesar da requisição estar sendo feita diferente estou com o mesmo problema... confirma pra mim se o webservice que você está usando é esse: * https://hom.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx*

Comment: Estou usando 'https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx'

Comment: em alguns lugares falam até possível problema com o serviço da receita, porem não faz sentido... pois tenho um outro programa que esta efetuando o download normalmente...
um rapaz me respondeu na minha pergunta dizendo que a receita esta mudando algumas validações... segue o link que ele disponibilizou: http://www.contabeis.com.br/noticias/35193/cfc-alerta-sobre-alteracoes-na-validacao-de-notas-fiscais-eletronicas/

Comment: Pois é, também li algo sobre usar 'NfeDistribuicaoDFe', para baixar o xml, mas não sei como...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este serviço saiu do ar mesmo, agora só com sefazDistDFe, ele retorna todas as chaves de acessos que foram emitida contra o CNPJ do certificado digital configurado no NFEPHP, aqui eu utilizo a versão 4.00 da API NFEPHP, você precisa entender como funciona o ULTNSU, através dele que você vai baixar todos os xml's em tempo "real"(pois depende da SEFAZ).

considerando que vc deu uma estudada no ultNSU vamos ao passo a passo.

1º ele só te fornece até 50 documentos(DF-e) por HORA.

2º você só pode chamar essa função de hora em hora caso o retorno seja menor de 50 e caso haja documento sem o manifesto se não vc será bloqueado temporáriamente pela SEFAZ (leia a NT).

3º obtendo a relação de nfs(chaves de acessos) você precisa MANIFESTA-LAS(NT) para obter o xml com validade jurídica, eu utilizo o MANIFESTO 210210(Ciência da Operação) pois é unica manifestação que deixa a nota em a ver ainda já que vc não a recebeu fisicamente, arquivo na pasta exemplos(4.00testaManifesta.php).

4º após o manifesto executa a função sefazDistDFe novamente, mesmo que já tenha executado dentro de uma hora dês de que tenha executado o manifesto antes, ATENÇÃO PARA O ultNSU.

5º nesta última execução sefazDistDFe ele já retornará (zipado) o xml com validade jurídica, gzdecode($base64_retornado_no_array)nele e armazene como quiser.

Comment: Favor nao adicionar email na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, atente-se a norma técnica **NT 2014.002.v.1.02**. Onde é claro na citação:

> Data de desativação dos Web Services NfeConsultaDest e NFeDownloadNF:
>   02/05/2017;

Sendo assim, ambos serviços estão desativados. Agora deve-se trabalhar com o serviço **NFeDistribuicaoDFe**, que funciona com ideologia de eventos e participantes do documento. Recomendo ler esta norma técnica de implementação:

https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=VcEhGZODuo4=

Este serviço muda totalmente, não sendo possível mais efetuar download via chave de acesso, pois os documentos são distríbuidos conforme sua disponibilidade no ambiente AN.

Comment: Ok Junior entendi essa parte, você teria um xml para demonstrar como ficaria a consulta com a chave de acesso, como descrito na documentação 'consChNFe' e 'chNFe'?

Comment: ótimo, consegui realizar o download da nfe

Comment: 1
votar contra
accept
O webservice DownloadNFe foi desativado conforme a NT 2014.002.v.1.02.

O webservice que você deve usar é:

https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx
Neste webservice você efetua a manifestação do destinatário e na próxima consulta ele retorna o XML completo da NFe.

Segue link do nota técnica: Nota Técnica 2014.002 - v1.02