# Consulta de NF-e com resposta: "Servico Paralisado sem Previsao"

Tags: nfe

Estou fazendo em um projeto um módulo de busca e download de XML de NF-e junto ao SEFAZ.

Fiz todas as configurações e apontei as requisições para o WebService informado no site da receita porém o mesmo esta retornando o seguinte erro:

```
<retDownloadNFe versao="1.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
    <verAplic>AN.DownNF_2.1.1</verAplic>
    <cStat>109</cStat>
    <xMotivo>Servico Paralisado sem Previsao</xMotivo>
    <dhResp>2017-08-15T09:58:12</dhResp>
</retDownloadNFe>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: qual UF e qual URL está usando ?

Comment: Acabaram de postar a mesma pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229137/download-nfe-nfephp , pode ser alguma mudança de serviço da receita, deve ter alguma relação com isso http://www.contabeis.com.br/noticias/35193/cfc-alerta-sobre-alteracoes-na-validacao-de-notas-fiscais-eletronicas/

Comment: UF - SP 
URL conforme informado no documentação:
 http://hom.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/webServices.aspx?tipoConteudo=Wak0FwB7dKs=#AN

Comment: Olha, parece que o serviço está paralisado. Não sei se você tem experiência com nota fiscal, mas isso é muito comum.

Comment: O pior é que na página de disponibilidade de serviços da SEFAZ aparece como se tudo estivesse funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Tive esse problema com o Sefaz a algum tempo e era por conta da alteração do método ConsultaDfe...

Comment: @JcSaint você tem a solução usada para esse problema?

Answer (score 2):

O webservice DownloadNFe foi desativado conforme a NT 2014.002.v.1.02.

O webservice que você deve usar é:

```
https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx
```

Neste webservice você efetua a manifestação do destinatário e na próxima consulta ele retorna o XML completo da NFe.

Segue link da nota técnica: [Nota Técnica 2014.002 - v1.02](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=VcEhGZODuo4=)

Fiz um exemplo bem simples, coloquei um button e um textbox em um form. Adicionei o endereço do webservice no projeto do visual studio como ServiceReference, assim o visual studio já gera as classe necessárias. Segue código:

Não esqueça de substituir os dados da código com os dados da sua empresa, e sem ler a nota técnica não tem como você entender o retorno do webservice.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoapClient consDFe = new NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoapClient();

        consDFe.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = ObterDoRepositorio();
        distDFeInt distDfe = new distDFeInt();
        distDfe.versao = TVerDistDFe.Item100;
        distDfe.tpAmb = TAmb.Item1;
        distDfe.cUFAutor = TCodUfIBGE.Item50;
        distDfe.ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.CNPJ;
        distDfe.Item = "000000000000000";
        distDFeIntDistNSU distNSU = new distDFeIntDistNSU();
        distNSU.ultNSU = "000000000";
        distDfe.Item1 = distNSU;
        string xmlEnvio = SerializeToString(distDfe);
        var removeq1 = new string[] { ":q1", "q1:" };
        foreach (var item in removeq1)
        {
            xmlEnvio = xmlEnvio.Replace(item, string.Empty);
        }
        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xmlEnvio);
        var asd = consDFe.nfeDistDFeInteresse(xml);
        textBox1.Text = asd.ToString();


    }

    public static X509Certificate2 ObterDoRepositorio()
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

        var collection = store.Certificates;
        var fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);
        var scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Certificados válidos:", "Selecione o certificado que deseja usar",
            X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

        if (scollection.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Nenhum certificado foi selecionado!");
        }

        store.Close();
        return scollection[0];
    }

    public static string SerializeToString(Object value)
    {
        var emptyNamepsaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        using (var stream = new StringWriter())
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value, emptyNamepsaces);
            return stream.ToString();
        }
    }
```

[Link no github](https://github.com/petinari/ConsultaDFeTeste)

Comment: boa tarde, estou com o mesmo problema e tentei utilizar esse webservice mencionado e não obtive sucesso... teria algum exemplo que possa me orientar melhor?

Comment: @ThiagoMottaBarboza, postei um código bem zoado de exemplo, mais está funcionado. Talvez sirva de base para você.

Comment: desculpe minha ignorância e se fiz algo errado mas utilizando esse código houve o mesmo retorno do erro... :/

Comment: Você criou um projeto do zero e incluiu o ServiceReference ?

Comment: Sim, agora esta dando erro no NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoapClient

Comment: acho que fi o erro coloquei nome da referencia errado esse referencia do client  é o server... vou arrumar aqui e te falo como ficou

Comment: desculpa a amolação mas tem como vc mandar esse projeto pra mim? não conseguir fazer funcionar...

Comment: @ThiagoMottaBarboza, vou adicionar no github e te passo.

Comment: obrigado irá me ajudar muito!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64081/discussion-between-thiago-motta-barboza-and-robss70).

Comment: @ThiagoMottaBarboza, a resposta está editada com o link no github.

Comment: <retDistDFeInt xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versao="1.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
  <verAplic>1.1.9</verAplic>
  <cStat>215</cStat>
  <xMotivo>Rejeicao: Falha no esquema xml</xMotivo>
  <dhResp>2017-08-18T19:33:35</dhResp>
  <ultNSU>000000000000000</ultNSU>
  <maxNSU>000000000000000</maxNSU>
</retDistDFeInt>

Comment: Mesmo erro Robss, nesse caso o NSU esta zerado porque ele retornaria tudo, porem acho que a mensagem xml deve ter sido alterada, vou dar uma pesquisada aqui, dando certo te aviso

Comment: Boa Tarde, pra quem passou pelo problema que eu passei, ta ai é só fazer o download.
https://github.com/thgmbz/DownloadXML-NT2014.002